# How can I select table records that have no relation records in doctrine 1.2

Tags: doctrine

How can I select all Table records which have no Relation records using a doctrine 1.2 query?

I've tried this kind of thing (below) but it tells me there is no t.Relations, probably because I have set the FK relation in the Relation table?
Seems like this should be very easy but can't figure it. Looked at sub queries but couldn't get my head around it to kno whether that was the right thing.
thanks.

```
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Table t')
    ->leftJoin('t.Relations r')
     ->where('t.user_id = ?',$userId)
     ->andWhere('t.Relations IS NULL')
        return $q->execute();
```

Much simplified schema:

```
Table:
  columns:    
    id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
    user_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
  relations:
    User:
      class:            User
      foreign:          id
      local:            user_id
      foreignAlias:     Users



Relation:
  columns:    
    table_id:
      type:             integer
      notnull:          true
  relations:
    Table:
      class:            Table
      foreign:          id
      local:            table_id
      foreignAlias:     Relations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your error message I am only guessing but the error is propably in your `andWhere(..)` statement. Table `t` doesn't have a property `Relation`, instead you want to check your table `r`:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Table t')
    ->leftJoin('t.Relations r')
    ->where('t.user_id = ?',$userId)
    ->andWhere('r.table_id IS NULL')
return $q->execute();
```

Comment: thanks this was the issue. I Was thinking backwards.